# Having difficulty saving VBA array to a range in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I've played around with this for several hours and am no closer to a solution.

When I create an array the following way, it outputs to a range without any difficulties:

```
Dim Destination As Range
Set Destination = NewSheet.Range("A1")

ReDim OutArray(1 To 1, 1 To NumArrayCols) As Variant
OutArray(1, 1) = "hello"
Destination.Resize(UBound(OutArray, 1), UBound(OutArray, 2)).Value = OutArray
```

However, when I create an output array in the following manner, it simply pastes a big blank array onto my spreadsheet. The first section of the code is probably mostly irrelevant, but I want to include it in case I'm missing anything:

```
ReDim OutArray(1, 1 To NumArrayCols) As Variant
Set ThisAtt = Wells.CurrWell.FirstAttribute(Skip:=False)
k = 1
OutArray(1, k) = "UWI"
Do
    ElevOffset = 0
    Set ThisAtt = Wells.CurrWell.CurrAttribute
    If InStr(LCase(ThisAtt.Name1), "elevation") Then
        OutArray(1, k + 1) = ThisAtt.Name1
        OutArray(1, k + 2) = ""
        OutArray(1, k + 3) = ThisAtt.Name2
        OutArray(1, k + 4) = ""
        ElevOffset = ElevOffset + 2
    Else
        OutArray(1, k + 1) = ThisAtt.Name1
        OutArray(1, k + 2) = ThisAtt.Name2
    End If
    OutArray(1, k + ElevOffset + 3) = "Recommend"
    OutArray(1, k + ElevOffset + 4) = "Rec. Value"
    OutArray(1, k + ElevOffset + 5) = "Comments"
    k = k + ElevOffset + 2 + AdditionalColumns
Loop While Not (Wells.CurrWell.NextAttribute(EnableSkipping:=False) Is Nothing)

Dim Destination As Range
Set Destination = NewSheet.Range("A1")
Destination.Resize(UBound(OutArray, 1), UBound(OutArray, 2)).Value = OutArray
```

It's strange, because every element in OutArray, upon inspection, seems to be there. My hand-generated array works fine, but the automatically-generated array--which seems similar in almost every way--doesn't work. Anyone know why?

Comment: just food for thought (doesn't answer your question, though): maybe you're still holding back some other code, but I don't see why you're using a multidimensional array when you're using it as a single-dimension one.

Comment: Yeah, good point. OutArray was multi-dimensional until I realized it wasn't going to hold all of my rows. I suppose I should just give it a single dimension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that it is just your `REDIM` statements.  In your first example you have this:

```
ReDim OutArray(1 To 1, 1 To NumArrayCols) As Variant
```

but in the second example you do this:

```
ReDim OutArray(1, 1 To NumArrayCols) As Variant
```

Notice the difference?  When you say `ReDim A(1 To 1)` both the upper and lower bounds are 1, but when you say just `Redim(1)` only the upper bound is 1, the lower bound is set to the default, which is zero (0).  Thus the two arrays are not the same shape/size and therefore in your second case your array does not fit correctly into the Destination Range.

Comment: Dang, that was probably it. I went ahead and converted OutArray to a one-dimensional array, though, because I didn't need the second dimension anymore, and that fixed the problem.